# How to create combinations of a password

Tags: brute-force, password-cracking

I don't remember my password, I can't remember exactly the variation.

How can I brute force all the permutations of a word knowing the following conditions:

1. Idea of the word (in my mind).
2. Lower and/or upper case.
3. Substitution of vowels with(out) numbers.

For example the following sound **stackoverflow** is a concept, can be written in password by the following combinations (having in mind the before rules):

```
stackoverflow
Stackoverflow
sTackoverflow
...
ST4CK0V35FL0W
```

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

The easy way i know is by using a python script to generate a password based on characters you remember.

for example

```
#!/usr/bin/python
import sys
import datetime
import os
import string, random
import itertools 

info = '''

######################################################
                By ACT Group inc                        
######################################################

    Alex
    Clairic
    Thuli
    The Pukiisefu Family
    http://actgroupinc.com

    Note: We Feel Proud To Be Who We are
######################################################

#######################################################################
# High Speed Word list Generator : Compatible To All Operating Systems #
#######################################################################
+++The little indemise Rose that grew on concrete++++
######################################################
'''

print info
chrs = list('STACKOVERFLOWstackoverflow1234567890')
l=6
k = l
j= 10
n= j-1
for i in xrange(k,n):
  for xs in itertools.product(chrs, repeat=i):
    sys.stdout.write(''.join(xs)+ '\n')
    sys.stdout.flush()
print '''
\t***************************************************
\t*       Successfully created thanks for using     *
\t***************************************************

'''
raw_input("[*] Press Enter For Exit")
```

you just need to change the minimum and maximum length here

**min**

```
l=6
```

**max**

```
j= 10
```

Note: you need python 27 installed in your system plus you may modify the code to save the words in a `txt` file

Comment: The problem here is that I want to follow the idea of the meaning, while with your script I am getting all permutations...